# Queries can not be applied to a response content of type 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent'. The response content must be an ObjectContent

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, knockout.js, odata

I am trying to download a file using knockout v3.2.0, webapi, odata and get this error when I try to return the file as HttpResponseMessage.

Here is my controller code:

```
 [EnableQuery]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAttachment([FromODataUri] int key)
{
    try
    { 
        DataAccess.Attachment a = db.Attachments.Where(x => x.AttachmentId == key).FirstOrDefault();               
        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
        memStream.Write(a.AttachmentData, 0, a.AttachmentData.Length);
        result.Content = new StreamContent(memStream);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = a.AttachmentName;
        return result;
        //return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, result);

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, exception.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

That's how I am trying to download from JavaScript:

```
    self.downloadDocument = function (attachmentId) {

        var serviceRequestUrl = dbhdd.buildUrl.buildSPContextUrl("/api/Attachments(" + 1 + ")");
        window.location.href = serviceRequestUrl;           

    };
```

Which gives me this error- Queries can not be applied to a response content of type 'System.Net.Http.StreamContent'. The response content must be an ObjectContent.

I am relatively new to this. Any guidance in fixing this/alternate approach will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I removed [EnableQuery] and it worked both in IE and Chrome!